# Caret package is not loading

Tags: r, r-caret, quick-install-package

I'm having problem with Caret package,
Please see the error below,

```
library(caret)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
> in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘caret’ was built under R version 4.0.2

I am using macOS Catalina.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Try `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Have you recently updated R? Sometimes this happens with problematic updates... try using [updateR](https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR)

Comment: I've just updated my R from CRAN, having problems with updateR as well :(

Comment: Thanks all, I reinstalled and every thing is working now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when moving from 4.0 to 4.1 and reinstalling `ggplot2`
Basically when loading `vctrs` it was using the `libR.dylib` from the R.Framework 4.0 not the 4.1 (and I removed the 4.0)

```
>library(ggplot2)
       
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in
     dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): unable to load shared 
object '/Users/xxxx/Library/R/4.1/library/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so':
           dlopen(/Users/xxxx/Library/R/4.1/library/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so, 6): 
Library not loaded: 
     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/lgzdl/Library/R/4.1/library/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so
Reason: image not found
```

My temporary solution has been to duplicate the 4.1 and renamed it 4.0. At, least for now > `library(vctrs)` is not throwing an error!
There must be a lingering reference to the R.Framework 4.0? somewhere?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this problem with latest release R-4.0.2.pkg in [www.r-project.org](http://www.r-project.org) -> Download -> CRAN and select your country.